# Python Bcrypt working only in Python Interpretor

Tags: python, bcrypt

I am wanting to use the Bcrypt module. I have this for quick testing purposes, as follows:

```
import bcrypt

password = b"super secret password"

hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed):
    print("It matches!")
else:
    print("Password doesnt match")
```

When trying to run this, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bcrypt.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "/Users/Kai/playground/bcrypt.py", line 5, in <module>
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
AttributeError: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'hashpw'
```

When trying to run this inside of the Python Interpreter *WITHIN* the "playground" directory I receive the same error.

**But** when I go to my home directory `~/` and run the same code through the Python Interpreter it works perfectly fine
[image: Python 3.5.2 Interpreter]

I have done both `pip3 install bcrypt --upgrade` & `pip install bcrypt --upgrade`.

I am wanting to find out what I can do to fix the issue, I have also uninstalled and reinstalled Python3 as well.

Comment: Did you call your file `bcrypt.py`? If so, don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your file and the library file are called the same.